# Why AWS Graph Explorer when connected to Gremlin server doesn't show the edges between vertices?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin-server, graph-explorer

I have cloned the AWS Graph Explorer on my local machine and then connected it to a Gremlin server (Started with the prebuilt Modern example). The problem here is that it shows me that the edges exist but doesn't show them on Graph.

[image]

AWS Graph Explorer v1.2.0

I've tried to explore the tool in the hope that I can find a configuration for the edges to make them appear but I couldn't find anything.